# Data labling in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Should be easy, I have negative values in a Highcharts bar chart that when I make the format ${y} the value comes out as $-157, what is the correct syntax to make the label -$157?

Thanks,

CM

Comment: Can you please add in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if there is a built-in option in Highcharts to do this for currencies, but a way you could achieve this is by using the [**`formatter`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.formatter) callback like this:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return (this.y >= 0 ? '' : '-') + '$' + Math.abs(this.y)
  }
}
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/4o7k210s/